# MICE for longitudinal data - shall I include both id and time variable for imputing outcome

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multiple-imputation, mice

The missing variable in my longitudinal data set is the outcome variable. I try to use mice in R to do multiple imputation. The final model is mixed effect model fitted by lmer. The data set contains two measure time points, baseline and year 1. Shall I include both the id variable and time variable in predicting the outcome (i.e., set pred[,id] <- 1 and pred[,time] <- 1)? I'm trying to use pmm and norm as the prediction method for not, not considering the 2l.norm/2l.pmm method because they run too slow.

Comment: Sorry if I misinterpret your post, but if we are missing the outcome variable then it is different conceptual to missing a predictive feature that ultimately we don't explicitly model for. Predictive imputation is a pretty slippery slope and we should do a lot of sensitivity analysis. I would say that if the missing data are not a major issue (and probably MCAR), then excluding those instances with missing outcome may be the best option. In general if the *outcome* is missing then imputing doesn't really affect the analysis (e.g.Outcome-sensitive multiple imputation: a simulation study (2017))